# Cropping into an image in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Is it possible without messing with core to get WP to crop 'into' an image. So for example I have an image which is 800 x 800 and I would like it to crop it to 400 x400 by cropping top / bottom and left/right, in effect losing 200px off each side of the image.

In this example image. The cropping I am trying to achieve would give me a close-up of the mountains and part of the sun only.

[image: Mountains and sun]

Hoping not to reply on a plugin.Thnx

Comment: When you say crop do you mean zoom into?

Comment: I suppose so. But I wouldn't be making it bigger - I just want to be left with 2 image. One which is 800x800 and one which is a cropped down version at 400x400.

Answer (score 0):

i think this function will help you.

```
<?php add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop ); ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `$crop` fits in the smallest dimension and crops the rest. So _either_ top and bottom or left and right. I would like both to happen.

Comment: Dear you must read it http://www.escalation-point.com/2012/09/image-cropping-in-wordpress-working-with-what-we-have/